# That car, to me, is what your house is to you/That car is to me what your house is to you

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure, analogy

That car, to me, is what your house is to you.

That car is to me what your house is to you.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think one of them is incorrect?

Comment: I usually hear people using the second.

Comment: For its symmetry, I would use the second one. Neither of them are ungrammatical, thought.

Comment: You might want to use _like_ before _what_ in the first sentence: That car, to me, is _like_ what your house is to you. Still I don't see it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider both sentences correct.

The parenthesised *to me* in the first one is rather unusual and puts a strong emphasis on this part, i.e., that this point of view is yours and probably limited to you.